# Visual studio 2008 creating Sharepoint Workflow missing

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow

I've installed visual studio 2008 on my vpc sharepoint 2007 developing machine.

I've installed the MOSS SDK and the WSS SDK And Sharepoint extensions for VS2008, and the WSPBuilder extentions.

When i want to create a Sharepoint Workflow, the templates are missing. Is it not possible ot create a sharepoint workflow with Visual Studio 2008 (Standard)?

What wrong with my configuration????

Answer (score 0):

You mean you don't have the option when creating a new project? (File -> New project)

Also, be sure to choose .NET Framework 3.0 or 3.5 in the right upper corner in the New project dialog.

[image: Visual Studio 2008 SharePoint Workflow project]